# How to properly rewrite $.fn.position function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to make default collision = "fit" everywhere instead of "flip". So I decided to rewrite the $.fn.position function. However, something breaks and it does not work: The  element does not move and no error is displayed. It just does nothing. I have no clue why. Here is what I wrote:

```
(function($) {
    var orig = $.fn.position;
    $.fn.position = function(options){
        if ( options ){if ( !options.collision ){
            options.collision = "fit";
        }}
        return orig.apply(this, options);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Looks ok to me. If there is a better way to do it or how to fix this thing please help.

Thank you

EDIT:
I am an idiot. Gotta use arguments with the orig apply.:

```
(function($) {
    var orig = $.fn.position;
    $.fn.position = function(options){
        if ( options ){
            if ( !options.collision ){
                options.collision = "fit";
            }
        }
        return orig.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? "Does not work" doesn't give us much insight.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defaulting the value when there's no `options`

```
(function($) {
    var orig = $.fn.position;
    $.fn.position = function(options){
        if (!options) {
             options = {collision: "fit"}
        }

        if ( !options.collision ){
            options.collision = "fit";
        }
        return orig.apply(this, options);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use `extend` method:

```
(function($) {
    var orig = $.fn.position;
    $.fn.position = function(options) {
       options = $.extend({collision: "fit"}, options);
       return orig.apply(this, options);
    }
})(jQuery);
```